# Fade Transition Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small slideshow in my `index.html` file written in Javascript that currently just jumps from image to image. I was hoping to find a fade effect that I could add so it fades into one image and out to the next after a set time. However I'm fairly new to Javascript and not too sure how to go about it. Here is what I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--          
    var step=1 
    function slide() {
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<10)
            step++
        else
            step=1
        setTimeout("slide()",2500)
    }
    slide()
  //-->
</script>
```

Comment: Easily done with jQuery. If you want to stick with JavaScript alone, there are dozens of scripts out there, a simple Google search will find. If you want to write it yourself, most would ask that you at least make some effort before asking your question.

Comment: I have looked around the problem is i have no idea how to link two different scripts together...

Comment: `eval("image"+step+".src")`???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how jQuery is doing that, but [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) is the way to do it.

It's really small code and will perform way better than any JavaScript solution.

You can refer to the example here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

CSS3 transitions are supported by all current browsers. IE9 doesn't seem to have it and instead of nice fading it will instantly change images. So it should be safe.

Comment: The script treats the images like a slide show and will autmoatically load the next image inline in its place. There is no hovering or linking at all. Additionally Css3 is still a little risky and means more work finding the work arounds for other browsers.

Comment: Even though CSS3 is not universally supported by every browser you may encounter, this is as good a solution as any.

Comment: @user2220339 recommend you preload your images. you may never get the fade effect you want, if you are loading your images as needed. See Demo 6 on the CSS3 example.

Comment: @user2220339 CSS3 is supported by all current browsers.